# Open ports are not shown on screen and not stored in db

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

I am new to Kali Linux. After running few commands on metasploit , the commands are running perfectly but display is not as shown in book. I am running this in Virtual box in windows 7

My screen display
[image]

Display from book

[image]

`[*] 192.168.1.155 is running Windows XP Service Pack 2 (language: English)
(name:DOOKIE-FA154354) (domain:WORKGROUP)` is not displayed or related to this.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Might it be that the host you are scanning cannot be identified by this module? What version of Windows is the target host running?

Comment: Windows 7 @returneax

Comment: You should stick to the environment used in the book, and therefore setup a Windows XP virtual machine otherwise most of the examples and exercises will likely not work.

Comment: Which version of MSF are you using? is it updated? If THREADS is *required* why you didn't set it? This question is product related and a bit broad, do some research first, here's the [source code](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_version.rb) which by the looks of it on Line 56 it's the fingerprint, on line 66 is tested and Line 150 SHOULD print something if it fails, so... do some debugging... here's the [wiki](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki)